# Extract rows from multiple MySQL tables based on date

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have three MySQL tables, all with identical columns, as such:

```
ID | title   | description | date
---|---------|-------------|-----------
1  | Title 1 | Desc 1      | 2014-06-12
2  | Title 2 | Desc 2      | 2014-05-12
...
```

What I would like to do is extract all the rows from all three tables where the date is after a certain point, i.e. a month ago, for example, and order them in date order, newest first, in a new, combined table. I've tried various `JOINS` but none of the results I've managed to come up with so far give me what I need; what I seem to get is tables joined either left or right of each other, rather than rows being pulled into one 'master table'.

How would I go about creating the table I'm looking for?

Comment: "Joined left or right of each other" makes no sense, unless there's some relationship between the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is anything else going on here that makes this more complex, but I think this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.id = table_1.id
JOIN table_3 ON table_3.id = table_1.id
WHERE table_1.date >= '2014-05-12' /*one month ago or whatever date you want*/
ORDER BY table_1.date, DESC
```

OR if you want to change column names do this in your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT table_1.id as t1_id, table_2.id as t2_id, /*etc*/
```

Comment: This works, so thank you, however say I have six entries in each table, then I'm getting six duplicate results returned for each entry. Is there a way to avert this behaviour?

Comment: Ok, no prob...however if you are talking about column names you can change those by doing as (updated in my answer)